# Problem with showing HTML tags in Android Email client

Tags: javascript, android, html

I'm trying to fill a subject and a body of Android Email (or Gmail) Client from the web.

```
<button onclick="parent.location='mailto:?subject=Prijatelj ti preporučuje ponudu&amp;body=Ćao, pogledaj ovu ponudu na Grupovini! <br />http://localhost:8089/deal/Skocite-sa-padobranom<br />Skok sa padobranom<br />Skocite'">Pošalji @</button>
```

So basically it's a simple mailto script which has "
" HTML tags. This works fine on iPhone, i have new lines but not on Android which actually shows everything as text (it does not format it as HTML).

So the question is how to get new line on Android Email / Gmail client (\r\n does not works either)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

The specs of the mailto specifies that the body param is only the first line of the mail content...

Strange that iPhone do that...

or, I just found (not tested):

```
mailto:?to=email%40example.com&subject=mailto%20uri%20scheme&body=line1%0D%0Aline2&cc=email%40example.com&bcc=email%40example.com
```

Comment: Is there any workaround for this? Yes it works like a charm on iPhone.

Comment: That's it! Thanks a lot! This works both on iPhone and Android.